# Запрос из трех таблиц

Tags: mysql, sql

Пытаюсь выполнить вот такой просто запрос

```
SELECT O.id
FROM accer O
JOIN accer_links I ON I.pid =1
AND I.cid = O.id
JOIN catalog_chains P ON P.pidc !=29
ORDER BY I.sort
```

Но результат такой, как будто в предпоследней строчке нет != 29 все равно показывает элементы, у которых `P.pidc=29`, а мне надо `P.pidc!=29`

Я где-то скобку не закрыл?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `accer` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hidden` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `nal1` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `na2` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `nal3` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `nal4` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `nal5` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `kol_vo` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `dop_inf` text NOT NULL,
  `vnimanie` text NOT NULL,
  `recomend` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `gde` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;


INSERT INTO `accer` (`id`, `hidden`, `name`, `nal1`, `na2`, `nal3`, `nal4`, `nal5`, `kol_vo`, `dop_inf`, `vnimanie`, `recomend`, `gde`) VALUES
(3, 1, 'Галстук 11', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', 0, '1'),
(4, 1, 'ывапн', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 0, ''),
(5, 1, '23141324', '1324', '', '132', '', '4132', '', '41324', '', 0, '4'),
(6, 1, '1', '1', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', 0, ''),
(7, 1, '123222', '3123', '', '123', '12', '312312', '', '213', '', 0, '');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `accer_links` (
  `pid` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `cid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sort` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251;

--
-- Дамп данных таблицы `accer_links`
--

INSERT INTO `accer_links` (`pid`, `cid`, `sort`) VALUES
(1, 7, 7),
(1, 6, 6),
(2, 5, 5),
(1, 3, 3),
(2, 4, 4);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `catalog_chains` (
  `pidc` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `cidc` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251;

--
-- Дамп данных таблицы `catalog_chains`
--

INSERT INTO `catalog_chains` (`pidc`, `cidc`) VALUES
(28, 3),
(29, 6),
(29, 3);
```

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста пример входных данных и ваш результат(лучше сразу инсертами в табличку)

Comment: Я бы с удовольствием - только не понял, что сделать? Могу дамп бд скинуть - подойдет?

Comment: Добавил в стартовый топик все 3 таблицы.

Comment: условия джойна-то нет. Там должно быть условие соединения, а вы туда условие фильтрации пишете. В целом из данных совершенно не ясно кто такие `pidc` и `cidc`, `pid`, `cid`, на какие таблицы это ссылки

Comment: Я добавил в вопрос все 3 таблицы.

Comment: @ysmhypno знаете, когда название таблицы `accer` и `accer_links` и `catalog_chains`, то как понять на что ссылается `pidc`? Она совершенно ни о чем не говорит ибо ни в одном названии не фигурирует буква `p`. Названия должны быть говорящими. И в частности, если ссылка на столбец `id` таблицы `accer`, то должно быть `accer_id`, если на `catalog_chains`, то `catalog_chains_id` и т.д.

Comment: @ysmhypno тоже самое касается и выбора названия алиасов. Если `accer`, то алиас будет например `a`, если `accer_links`, то `al`. А то в итоге у вас всё в сокращении не то, что есть на самом деле - и читающий код просто не поймёт откуда такие буквы и названия всплыли. Особенно, если запрос будет не короткий, а строчек на 70-80. Это просто вам на будущее, чтобы вы знали, что так делать не стоит, стоит делать корректно))

Comment: Ну и хотелось бы узнать в итоге, что на что ссылается,

Comment: Спасибо за советы. В итоге таблица accer - будет хранить "товары". accer_links - разбитие товаров по категориям. catalog_chains - привязка товаров к другим товарам. Я хочу взять все товары (accer) из определенной категории (accer_links) и которые еще и не привязаны к товару с pidc=29 (catalog_chains). Без последний части код работал уже давно. Теперь я хочу добавить catalog_chains

Comment: @ysmhypno предположу что запрос будет такой: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/35e1f8/3 или такой http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/35e1f8/4 (вынес условия в...эм...условия). Но это лишь догадки, связанные с совсем неинтуитивными названием идентификаторов))

Comment: Спасибо! Буду дальше допиливать. Не додумался, что нужно все условия в одно место.

Comment: Вы что-то не договариваете. Я просто скопировал код создания и заполнения таблиц и ваш запрос. В результате запроса не выпадают записи с `p.idic = 29`